# How can I check the value of a span and if the value is something redirect the user?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to add google auth to website but the redirect isn't working. So, I want to manually redirect to another website with javascript if the value of the span is `<span id="connected7rduqfr6hg1s" style="">Signed in</span>` rederict ton example.org

Comment: Welcome to [so]! We will be glad to help if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [ask] a good question and [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `document.getElementById('connected7rduqfr6hg1s').textContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with a Javascript library, such as Jquery, is very easy, and you should really look into that.  However, assuming you don't want to or can't use Jquery, this is how you would do it in native Javascript on newer browsers.

```
var span = document.getElementById("connected7rduqfr6hg1s").firstChild;
if (span.nodeValue == "Signed in")
  window.location.assign("https://www.google.com");
```